# rake gems:install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When i run rake gems:install, i get the following error:

rake aborted! no such file to load -- aws/s3

I have installed the aws and the s3 gems so I don't quite understand why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The lib argument needs to be specified since it is different than the gem name. It should be:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to `config.gem 'aws-s3'` instead of `config.gem 'aws/s3'`